# Why my background image goes above when scroll the list?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

[image]

I have a scrolling list on my page with a repeating image background. My problem is that when I scroll my list the background image doesn't fill the page. My CSS is:

```
background: transparent url(images/Background-Screen.png) repeat 0 0 !important;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to prevent your background image to scroll?

`background-attachment:fixed; // cause default value is "scroll"`

in your case:

```
background: transparent url(images/Background-Screen.png) repeat 0 0 fixed !important;
```

Comment: @user2648752 works or not? What exactly you don't understand? The `background-attachment` property?

Comment: I write like this ..!! but not works. background-attachment:fixed;

             background : transparent url(images/Background-Screen.png) repeat 0 0 !important;

Comment: @user2648752 that's cause you need to set your background image to the body of your document. not to that DIV

Comment: @user2648752 how you expect me to change something I don't see?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
body {
    background-image: url(img.jpg);
    background-position: center top;
    background-size: 100% auto;
}
```

Or try this:

http://css-tricks.com/how-to-resizeable-background-image/

Comment: This issue only face when I put list upto the ipad height.Mean when I add list upto 13 or 14 element .

Comment: then you can use overflow: hidden; or overflow: auto;  on the container (with no fixed height)

Comment: may be this relates to your issue http://www.kylejlarson.com/blog/2011/fixed-elements-and-scrolling-divs-in-ios-5/